# Cobertura does not work with Java 9

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-9, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have been using Java 8, now trying to upgrade to java 9. Most of the things works except generation of unit test cases report, I am using Cobertura.

With Java 9 I get following error, seems like Cobertura still references tools.jar which is removed from Java 9.

> Failed to execute goal on *****: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for *****:abc:jar:0.0.1: Could not find
>   artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]

Can anybody tell me how to generate unit test cases report with Java 9? Can I continue to use Cobertura or switch to some other tool for unit test cases?

Comment: The same issue could be tracked under their [project issue#271](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/271) and about switching to some other tool, yes you can and which would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: "TheOni" considered the project almost dead as the last update was 2 years ago and suggested to switch to OpenClover.